# Enable photo (not in tab group) based on tab page showing VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tabs

I want to enable a photo in the upper right section of a Windows Form, but I can't figure out the way to set a photo to visible when one of the tab pages is selected.
Right now I have it set up as a visible = true when the tab page is clicked (the tab page itself not the tab button). What I want it to do is become visible when the tab button is clicked.

If this is still confusing I can expand more. Not sure what more you need.

Edit: I'm trying to do it without placing the photo within the tab page.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `TabControl` and show the appropriate image. There are a variety of ways to do this; the simplest is probably to have an array of `Image`s corresponding to the tabs:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly TabImages() As Image = {
    My.Resources.TheImageForTabOne,
    Image.FromFile("load/these/however/you/want")
}
```

and in the `SelectedIndexChanged` handler:

```
Me.MyPictureBox.Image = TabImages(Me.MyTabControl.SelectedIndex)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I found a different solution (yours might have worked just couldn't figure it out.)

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System. Event Args) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

If TabControl1.SelectedTab Is tbpBagel Then
  picname.Visible = True

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @JoshFerrell: Sorry, I misread - I thought you meant a different picture showed up for each tab. But yes, `SelectedIndexChanged` is the event you want anyway.